# How to convert dicom images to Jpg format in R

Tags: r, image-conversion, medical-imaging

How to convert Dicom images with file extension .dcm to Jpg or Png in R

I am attempting the following code in R, but getting error as *Error: '...' used in an incorrect context*

What is wrong in my below R code.

```
source("https://neuroconductor.org/neurocLite.R")
neuro_install('dcmtk')
install_dcmtk()
library(dcmtk)
setwd("D:/train/ID00007637202177411956430")
dcm<-readDICOMFile("27.dcm")
dcmj2pnm(dcm, outfile = tempfile(fileext = ".png"),opts = "--write-png", ...)
```

Comment: Do you want to convert it within your program? If not, you can simply use an online converter.

Comment: Yes want to convert within R.  Not sure what error I am doing in my above code

Answer (score -1):

Looking at the code for dcmj2pnm.R (https://github.com/muschellij2/dcmtk/blob/master/R/dcmj2pnm.R), it seems that it expects the first parameter to be a DICOM file name.  You seem to be passing it DICOM image in memory, not a file name.

Comment: Thanks.  I should have used file with .dcm extension in my dcmj2pnm command.